# Best way to update component after this handleClick?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have this function in a component. It requests a delete to an api. At the end of the function however I need to update the component so that the app re-renders the display thus removing a jsx element that rendered the object that was deleted. I know forceUpdate() is not recommended but it doesn't work in this code anyway. Anyone know why? And what is the better way to implement this component update? The backend is indeed deleting the requested object and the console log works btw.

```js
  handleClick() {
    const logId = this.props.log._id;  
    fetch(`/api/logs/${logId}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },  
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: logId
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => alert(res))
      .catch(err => alert(err))  
    this.forceUpdate()
    console.log('Deleted log"')
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use just `setState`? It will re-render your component automatically.

```
.then((res) => this.setState({ deletedId: logId }))
```

Then you can inform the user that specified `logId` was removed.

```
{this.state.deletedId && <span>deleted id: {this.state.deletedId}</span>}
```

Answer (score 1):

this.forceUpdate() is called even before fetch. Because fetch is a async operation. 
Trying setting state within the second then method of fetch.